# What set are these bags? Detectives wanted

Tags: sets

I just bought this collection of LEGO parts. I am mostly curious about the sealed bags. Most are numbered 2011.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

More detailed pictures: [http://imgur.com/a/ebkvz](https://imgur.com/a/ebkvz)

Answer (score 2):

The bags with orange parts and some of the pieces in the box are from [Arctic Base Camp (60036)](http://brickset.com/sets/60036-1/Arctic-Base-Camp):

[image: 60036]

As Bill pointed out, the lime bag is from [Titanium Command Rig (8964)](http://brickset.com/sets/8964-1/Titanium-Command-Rig):

[image: 8964]

The others have been repackaged, so it's tough to know exactly what sets they come from.

[Construction site (7633)](http://brickset.com/sets/7633-1/Construction-Site) obviously has at least a few pieces present in the box:

[image: 7633]

The base to the tow truck from [Garage (7642)](http://brickset.com/sets/7642-1/Garage) is also in the box:

[image: 7642]

Some of the elements from [Drawbridge Defense (7079)](http://brickset.com/sets/7079-1/Drawbridge-Defense) are still assembled in the box:

[image: 7079]

At least the nose from [Police Pontoon Plane (7723)](http://brickset.com/sets/7723-1/Police-Pontoon-Plane) is also present in the box:

[image: 7723]

The base from [Woody and Buzz to the Rescue (7590)](http://brickset.com/sets/7590-1/Woody-and-Buzz-to-the-Rescue) is also in there:

[image: 7590]

The top from [Republic Attack Shuttle (8019)](http://brickset.com/sets/8019-1/Republic-Attack-Shuttle) is in the box as well:

[image: 8019]

Answer (score 0):

The lime green pieces in bag 4 look like they may be from Power Miners 8964.